# How does dependency injection work in Cucumber?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, junit, dependency-injection, cucumber

I have been trying to inject `webdriver` into the steps.  I have used [this instructions](https://github.com/salman-/cucumber-selenium/wiki/How-does-dependency-injection-in-Cucumber-work%3F/_edit) and it works well.

The idea is to inject WebDriver into steps classes as a service. At the initial step, you need to add the following dependency.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-spring</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.5</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

There are three main classes which are involved in the dependency injection. Here we introduce them one by one.

[image]

BaseUtil

BaseUtil is the class which has an attribute for WebDriver from Selenium. The class is quite simple:

```
public class BaseUtil {

 private WebDriver driver;

 public WebDriver getDriver() {return driver;}

 public void setDriver(WebDriver driver) { this.driver = driver;}
}
```

**Hook**

The Hook class contains `@Before, @After`. The method testInitializer() is responsible to load the the webDriver **file** and create an instance, while the method testTearDown() is responsible for closing the browser.

```
    public class Hook extends BaseUtil{
    
    BaseUtil base;

    
    @Before
    public void testInitializer(){
        File file = new 
            File(IgniteTaskApplication.class.getClassLoader().getResource("driver/chromedriver.exe").getFile());
        String driverPath=file.getAbsolutePath();
        System.out.println("Webdriver is in path: "+driverPath);
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",driverPath);
        base.setDriver(new ChromeDriver());
    }
    
    public Hook(BaseUtil base) {
        this.base = base;
    }

    @After
    public void tearDownTest(){
        base.getDriver().close();
    }
}
```

**Steps**

And the steps class contains the steps which came from compiled features file. To compile the feature file in Eclipse you need to have Eclipse-Cucumber plugin installed in your Eclipse.

```
public class ClickButton_Steps extends BaseUtil{
    BaseUtil base;
    
    public ClickButton_Steps(BaseUtil base){
        super();
        this.base=base;
    }
    
    @When("^I clcik on the button$")
    public void i_clcik_on_the_button() throws Throwable {
        cb=new ClickButtonPage(base.getDriver());
        cb.navigator();
    }

        // The other steps ...
}
```

How do i run it?

**Open the feature file -> Run as -> Run with Junit**

***Question***

I am wondering **what is the order of running methods in a way which it leads to dependency injection?**

I guess the order is as following:

1. Junit calls `@Before` method which is `testInitializer()`
2. The `testInitializer()`is in Hook class so it needs to make an instance of `Hook` class.
3. It leads to call the constuctor of the Hook class.

But, i cannot understand the rest of the steps. Maybe even it is not true at all. I mean, **I have a functional code but i cannot explain how it works?**

Comment: Link to instructions in top line is broken

Answer (score 1):

As I understand you correctly you use JUnit as a test framework with cucumber-spring. JUnit provides the following lifecycle.

When you annotate the method with annotation @Before that it will call this method before each test that you have. 
As for @After could be used for cleaning resources and call after each test.

Your test flow when you run the test:

- testInitializer
- i_clcik_on_the_button
- tearDownTest

In addition, you could use logging (slf4j) instead of System.out.println and it will be easier to track test flow.